# React `react-router-dom` always show the `NotFound` page, home page active class not removed as well

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am using `"react-router-dom": "^6.4.1"` with my current app. I am getting 2 issues.

1. when navigating to other page, home page `active` class not removed. still both new page and home page are having `active` class name.
2. I am always getting a `NotFound` page. Even when I click on other page, I am in the `NotFound` page.

What is the issue I am encountering?

Code for scenario 1:

```
{links.map(({ name, path }, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={index}>
      <NavLink
        onClick={() =>
          setIsNavShowing((prev) => !prev)
        }
        to={path}
        className={({ isActive }) =>
          isActive ? 'active-nav' : ''
        }
      >
        {name}
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  );
})}
```

Senario 2:

```
const App: FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="gallery" element={<Gallery />} />
        <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="plans" element={<Plans />} />
        <Route path="trainers" element={<Trainers />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Link array:

```
export const links:TypeLink[] = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    path: '/'
  },
  {
    name: "About",
    path: '/about'
  },
  {
    name: "Gallery",
    path: '/gallery'
  },
  {
    name: "Plans",
    path: '/plans'
  },
  {
    name: "Trainers",
    path: '/trainers'
  },
  {
    name: "Contact",
    path: '/contact'
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the `links` value that is mapped?

Comment: @DrewReese - Link array added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The active `NavLink` link issue can be resolved by specifying the `end` prop.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link)

> ```
> declare function NavLink(
>   props: NavLinkProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => string | undefined);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

> If the `end` prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched
> as "active" when its descendant paths are matched.

```
{links.map(({ name, path }, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={index}>
      <NavLink
        onClick={() =>
          setIsNavShowing((prev) => !prev)
        }
        end // <-- specify end prop
        to={path}
        className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "active-nav" : "")}
      >
        {name}
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  );
})}
```

[image: Edit react-react-router-dom-always-show-the-notfound-page-home-page-active-class]

The only issue I see with the routes is that the `Home` component is being rendered on `"/home"` instead of `"/"` like the link is linking to.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
  <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
  <Route path="gallery" element={<Gallery />} />
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> // <-- render on "/" instead of "/home"
  <Route path="plans" element={<Plans />} />
  <Route path="trainers" element={<Trainers />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Now I am click on `Home` NotFound page loading. others are working fine

Comment: @3gwebtrain That was the only route I saw that had an issue. The `Home` component is rendered on `"/home"` but the link for it links to `"/"`, and since there is no route for `"/"` the `NotFound` route/component is rendered. Either change the link to `"/home"` to match the route, or change the route `"/"` to match the link.

Comment: Amazing Drew, Thanks for the sandbox, forked for future use 